# jquery.countdown.js showing wrong date

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Following is the code i am using on jquery countdown but it is calculating wrong date.i need to set it to 1st feb 2015 , tried setting the month to 01 (month starts from zero) but in this case counter disappers

```
<script>
    $('#clock').countdown('2015/02/01').on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
        + '<ul class="co"><li><a href=""><span>%-d</span><br>Days </a></li>'
        + '<li><a href=""><span>%H</span><br> Hours </a></li>'
        + '<li><a href=""><span>%M</span><br> Minutes </a></li>'
        + '<li><a href=""><span>%S</span><br> Seconds</a></li></ul>'));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you say it's calculating the wrong date - can you elaborate?  what date is it giving you (and give the corresponding time that you notice this happen for context)

Comment: and I think you need `.countdown({until: new Date(2015, 2-1, 1)})` instead  -  see reference guide: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html  -  also dont need to declare `var $this = ...` if you're not gonna use it again

Comment: Hey himanshu did my answer help you with your problem?  If so could you mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to create a countdown until February 1st, 2015 you should use the following code:

```
$('#clock').countdown({until: new Date(2015, 12-11, 1)}))
```